# Making concurrent canvas animations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm learning JavaScript canvas recently, and I came up two ways of making animations. I searched google for a while but cannot determine which way is correct.

Say I have want to render different objects doing different things on the canvas with 30 fps. There're 2 ways to achieve this.

For both 2 ways, there should be a main `setInterval` function that `draw` all objects in 30fps.

1. Every object has a `nextframe(user_response)` method, which changes the 'status' of this object according to user response, and is called by a main `setInterval` 30 times ps. The main `setInterval` need to pass user responses into each `nextframe(...)` in some way, and it calls `draw` for each object.
   --The problem with this approach is that all `nextframe` for all objects are called per frame, taking system resources.
2. Objects implement their own animation methods with`setInterval`. These methos get called according to user response, changing the object 'status' 30 times per second. And the main `setInterval` function only calls `draw` for each object in 30fps, behaving like 'taking pictures' of each object's status. The object statuses change independently in other threads. So there's always one main thread of 30fps running, and if there're `m` objects animated and `n` object not animated at the moment, there're `(m+1)` threads in total --The problem with this that when many objects are animated I have many threads running, which also takes system resources.

So, which one is a more appropriate method? or are they both wrong? :>
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is the good one. Except you should user requestNextAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.

To solve your problem of resources, you can add conditions in the draw() methods to avoid redrawing if it is not necessary. But I think you need to redraw for each frames because you must clear your stage in order to draw the moving objects.